# Django migration issue with Oracle Database

Tags: django, django-models, cx-oracle

I am having some trouble migrating my Django database to Oracle. When do the makemigrations, there are no issues. But when I migrate, I get the following error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: Products, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying Products.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 250, in apply_migration
    self.recorder.record_applied(migration.app_label, migration.name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 71, in record_applied
    self.migration_qs.create(app=app, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 417, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1292, in execute_sql
    return self.connection.ops.fetch_returned_insert_id(cursor)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\DjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\operations.py", line 228, in fetch_returned_insert_id
    return int(cursor._insert_id_var.getvalue())
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

But when you look in the database, you can see the tables:

[Database Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaXdl.png)

My Model is:

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    title       = models.TextField()    
    description = models.TextField()    
    comments    = models.TextField(default='No comments!')
    featured    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Below is 0001_initial.py:

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Product',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.TextField()),
                ('description', models.TextField()),
                ('comments', models.TextField(default='No comments!')),
                ('featured', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

And the table in the database:

```
Name        Null?    Type       
----------- -------- ---------- 
ID          NOT NULL NUMBER(11) 
TITLE                NCLOB      
DESCRIPTION          NCLOB      
COMMENTS             NCLOB      
FEATURED    NOT NULL NUMBER(1)
```

I tried dropping the tables, deleting the cache folder and running makemigrate/migrate. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the migration file at the same time as dropping the table?

Comment: @iain-shelvington Yeah, deleted the files inside migrations. Same result. Though the missing field in the table is now there:

Comment: (DjangoEnv) C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\PiSquareDjangoWebsite\src>python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'Products':
  Products\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Product

`Name        Null?    Type`
`----------- -------- ----------`
`ID          NOT NULL NUMBER(11)`
`TITLE                NCLOB`
`DESCRIPTION          NCLOB`
`COMMENTS             NCLOB`
`FEATURED    NOT NULL NUMBER(1)`

return int(cursor._insert_id_var.getvalue())
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'